How can I disable Underlined Letters in KDE Plasma 5?
I'm using KDE Plasma 5 on Kubuntu 22.04 and I've been noticing underlined letters in menus, dialog boxes etc. I find them distracting and would like to disable them. Does anyone know how to turn off these underlined letters in KDE Plasma 5? Thanks in advance!


The underlined letters are the letters which you need to press together with the Alt-key to switch to the corresponding tab, e. g. pressing Alt+P would switch to the Previews tab. There is no way to configure that, you'll have to live with the underlined letters.
